# Java change color JLabel

Tags: java, colors, jlabel

I know how to change a color in java from a JLabel object if you do it like this

```
JLabel label = new JLabel("label text");
label.setForeground(Color.red);
```

but::

i create my JLabes dynamic like this

```
center.add(new JLabel("Antwoord Vraag"+ (i +1) +": "+antwoord.get(i),SwingConstants.LEFT));
```

How could i change the color of a JLabel object without giving the object a name.

Comment: What is center declared as?

Comment: Since there is no `JLabel` constructor that takes a color and `setForeground()` doesn't return a JLabel, you cannot.

Comment: The answer is you need to make a variable like in the first example, and then add that to your center object. Also, you are using the word 'dynamic' incorrectly

Comment: A bad way of doing this that you definitely shouldn't use is `center.add(new JLabel("Antwoord Vraag"+ (i +1) +": "+antwoord.get(i),SwingConstants.LEFT){{setForeground(Color.RED);}})`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for is a [builder pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Builder_pattern) for `JLabel`, which AFAIK does not exist.
You can either create your own builder class, or extend `JLabel` with your own class that takes color as constructor argument (which is weird since `JLabel` has many properties, imagine what happens if each of them ahd it's own special constructor).

**JLabelBuilder example:**

```
public class JLabelBuilder {
    private Color fColor;
    private String text;

    public void setForegroundColor(Color c) {
        fColor = c;
    }

    public void setText(String t) {
        text = t;
    }

    public JLabel build() {
        if (text != null && fColor != null) {
            JLabel label = new JLabel(text);
            label.setForeground(fColor);
            return label;
        } else {
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
center.add(new JLabelBuilder()
                   .setText("Antwoord Vraag" + (i + 1) + ": " + antwoord.get(i))
                   .setForegroundColor(Color.red)
                   .build());
```

Anyway, I don't see the harm in two more lines of code. Explicitly declaring your object variable is also a good practice for readability reasons. This will also work inside a loop:

```
for(int i = 0 ; i < maxCounter ; i++) {
    String text = "Antwoord Vraag" + (i + 1) + ": " + antwoord.get(i);
    JLabel label = new JLabel(text, SwingConstants.LEFT);
    label.setForeground(Color.red);
    center.add(label);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of ways you can do this, but not with the standard `JLabel` - you'll need your own subclass or helper. For example:

```
public class CLabel extends JLabel
{
    public CLabel(String text)
    {
        super(text);
    }

    public CLabel(String text, Color color)
    {
        super(text);
        setForeground(color);
    }

    public CLabel withColor(Color color)
    {
        setForeground(color);
        return this;
    }
}
```

Then you can do either of the following:

```
    new CLabel("Hello", Color.RED);
    new CLabel("Hello").withColor(Color.RED);
```

Answer (score 0):

You're going to have to split this up into multiple lines:

```
JLabel label = new JLabel("Antwoord Vraag"+ (i +1) +": "+antwoord.get(i),SwingConstants.LEFT);
label.setBackground(Color.GREEN);
label.setOpaque(true);
center.add(label);
```

PS- I'm going to start calling them "JLabes" too- much trendier! :p

Answer (score -1):

This line:

```
center.add(new JLabel("Antwoord Vraag"+ (i +1) +": "+antwoord.get(i),SwingConstants.LEFT));
```

is in a for loop for creating more JLabels

```
    for(int i = 0; i<maxCounter; i++)
    {

        // Goede Antwoorden toevoegen aan de center
       center.add(new JLabel("Antwoord Vraag"+ (i +1) +": "+antwoord.get(i),SwingConstants.LEFT));                      
    }
```

Because this is not working in the for loop:

```
    JLabel label[i] = new JLabel("Antwoord Vraag"+ (i +1) +": "+antwoord.get(i),SwingConstants.LEFT);
```

Is there a sollution to change the color

I have solved the problem.
Before i start the loop i creat a array:

```
JLabel[] labels = new JLabel[maxCounter];
```

Then in the forloop:

```
           labels[i] = new JLabel("Antwoord Vraag"+ (i +1) +": "+antwoord.get(i),SwingConstants.LEFT);
           // verander de kleur van de labels
           labels[i].setForeground(rood);
           center.add(labels[i]);
```

Comment: See my answer. There's no problem to declare the same variable over and over inside a loop. Just get rid of the `[i]` array operator and your fine.

Comment: Do you need the `JLabel`s outside the loop? Otherwise the array is redundant.

Comment: i have delete the array and the [i] array operator and it works fine. Thx Elist

Comment: I get the feeling that you need to learn how to use stackOverFlow. You got 4 answers and did not respond or vote any of them. Instead you answered your own qeustion with another question instead of editing, and then you changed the qeustion-answer into a wrong answer. Please listen to people who are trying to help you and make efforts to vote / comment / accept next time.